# Filter log by conversion pattern [%t]

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

```
I am using the log4j2 version 2.11.1. I have the below pattern in log4j2.xml

"%d %-5r %-5p [%t] [%x] [%c] [%M] [%L] - %m%n".
I want to filter the logs on [%t]

I tried RegexFilter=".Coherence." and ThreadContextMapFilter. Filter is not working.
```

`<Configuration xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config" status="DEBUG">
   <Properties>
     <Property name="basePath">../Log4j2Example/logs</Property>
  </Properties>
   <Appenders>
     <!-- File Appender -->
     <File name="FILE" fileName="${basePath}/logfile.log" append="true" >
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5r %-5p [%t] [%x] [%c] [%M] [%L] - %m%n" />
         <RegexFilter regex=".*Cohernce.*" useRawMsg="true" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT"/>
     </File>
     <File name="STRINGFILE" fileName="${basePath}/logfileAA.log" append="true" >
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5r %-5p [%t] [%x] [%c] [%M] [%L] - %m%n" />
      <RegexFilter regex=".*Cohernce.*" onMatch="ACCEPT" useRawMsg="true" onMismatch="DENY"/>
     </File>

    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
     <Logger name="com.jcg.logging" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="FILE" />
        <AppenderRef ref="STRINGFILE" />    
     </Logger>

     <Logger name="com.jcg.logging" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="FILEA"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="STRINGFILE" />
     </Logger>

    <Root level="DEBUG">
      <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />
    </Root>
   </Loggers>
</Configuration>`

2019-06-12 10:41:06,262 486977 DEBUG [Coherence:BaseCacheService2Worker:0] [[]] [com.test.logging.Aggregator] [aggregate] [46] - Inside aggregate method-START
2019-06-12 10:41:06,263 486979 DEBUG [Serivee:Coherence:BaseCacheService2Worker] [[]] [com.test.abc.xyz] [XXX] [246] - Inside  method -START

Any line contains the **Coherence** should be redirected to log4j2 Appenders "STRINGFILE" & "FILE" Appender does not log it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [RoutingAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RoutingAppender) and the [getThreadName](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/LogEvent.html#getThreadName--) method of the [LogEvent](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-core/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/logging/log4j/core/LogEvent.html) to do what you want.

Here is a simple Java class to generate some logging:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class SomeClass {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();   

    public static void main(String[] args){

        log.debug("This is some debug!");
        log.info("Here's some info!");
        log.error("Some error happened!");

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {

                log.info("Here's some info!");
                log.error("Some error happened!");
            }

        }, "foo.Cohernce.1234");
        t.start();
        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            log.error(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the log4j2.xml configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>

     <File name="FILE" fileName="logs/logfile.log" append="true" >
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5r %-5p [%t] [%x] [%c] [%M] [%L] - %m%n" />
     </File>
     <File name="STRINGFILE" fileName="logs/logfileAA.log" append="true" >
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5r %-5p [%t] [%x] [%c] [%M] [%L] - %m%n" />
     </File>

        <Routing name="Routing">
            <Routes>
                <Script name="RoutingInit" language="JavaScript"><![CDATA[
                  if (logEvent.getThreadName() != null && logEvent.getThreadName().contains("Cohernce")) {
                        "Cohernce";
                    }else{
                        "OTHER";
                    }]]>
                </Script>
                <Route ref="FILE" />
                <Route ref="STRINGFILE" key="Cohernce" />
            </Routes>
        </Routing>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Routing" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

This is the output written to logfile.log

```
2019-06-15 01:30:00,705 645   DEBUG [main] [[]] [example.SomeClass] [main] [12] - This is some debug!
2019-06-15 01:30:00,815 755   INFO  [main] [[]] [example.SomeClass] [main] [13] - Here's some info!
2019-06-15 01:30:00,818 758   ERROR [main] [[]] [example.SomeClass] [main] [14] - Some error happened!
```

This is the output written to logfileAA.log

```
2019-06-15 01:30:00,822 762   INFO  [foo.Cohernce.1234] [[]] [example.SomeClass] [run] [21] - Here's some info!
2019-06-15 01:30:00,832 772   ERROR [foo.Cohernce.1234] [[]] [example.SomeClass] [run] [22] - Some error happened!
```